# How to use {domain} instead of {ip}/moodle for Moodle Instance URL?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, moodle

I've configured the site's Apache config as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin server@gmail.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But the domain just won't work. I don't even know why I tried the same thing with an HTML page and it worked. I know I should've asked this on the moodle forum, but the interface there just confuses me.

I've tried to look in many answers but none has been a solution for me (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXEy4.png).

Also if it's not clear: DNS is ready, I have an A record pointing to the site's IP. If relevant, the machine is Ubuntu 18.04, and the webserver is Apache 2.

Comment: "just won't work" means what exactly? What error / unexpected behaviour do you get when you try to navigate to the URL?

Comment: It just says 'This site can't be reached' and '{domain} refused to connect'. If it were an HTML dir, it would just serve it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to just reinstall the moodle instance. I used this tutorial: https://musaamin.web.id/how-to-install-moodle-on-ubuntu-18-04/. And make sure your domain has an A record pointing to your server's IP.